# Determinant of a matrix with 0 elements above the second diagonal

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Good day to all!

I am calculating the determinant of the following $(K + 1) \times (K + 1)$ matrix?
$$
{\bf A} = \left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
a_{K1} & a_{K 2} & a_{K 3} & \dots & a_{K K} & c_{K K} \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & \dots & b_K & b_{K + 1}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$

I have attempted to decompose it by the first row:
$$
\det{\bf A} = \left(-1\right)^{1 + 1} a_{1 1} \cdot \det{\bf A}_{1, 1} + \left(-1\right)^{2 + 1} a_{1 2} \cdot \det{\bf A}_{2, 1},
$$
where ${\bf A}_{1, 1}$ is obtained from ${\bf A}$ by excluding its first column and first row:
$$
{\bf A}_{1, 1} = \left(\begin{matrix}
a_{22} & a_{23} & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
a_{K2} & a_{K 3} & a_{K 4} & \dots & a_{K K} & c_{K K} \\
b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & \dots & b_K & b_{K + 1}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
${\bf A}_{2, 1}$ is defined similarly.

${\bf A}_{1, 1}$ can be further decomposed, but at each step, I will have 2 non-zero elements at first row.

Is there a short way to calculate $\det{\bf A}$?

Comment: This is called a [Hessenberg Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix)  and efficient algorithms do exist.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. I tried to find an efficient algorithm, but came up with the following iterative formula only: https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2119&context=article
I will still need to calculate a lot of determinants.